getting last character from a string that may or may not be unicode
I'm parsing a file that contains both alpha strings and unicode/UTF-8 strings containing IPA pronunciations.
I want to be able to obtain the last character of a string, but sometimes those characters occupy two spaces, e.g.
syl = 'tyl'  # plain ascii
last_char = syl[-1]
# last char is 'l'

syl = 'tl̩'  # contains IPA char
last_char = syl[-1]
# last char erroneously contains: '̩' which is a diacritical mark on the l
# want the whole character 'l̩'

If I try using .decode(), it fails with:

'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

How to obtain the last character of the Unicode/UTF-8 string (when you don't know if it's Ascii or Unicode string)?
I guess I could use a lookup table to known characters and if it fails, go back and grab syl[-2:]. Is there an easier way?

In response to some comments, here is the complete list of IPA characters I've collected so far:
a, b, d, e, f, f̩, g, h, i, i̩, i̬,
j, k, l, l̩, m, n, n̩, o, p, r, s,
s̩, t, t̩, t̬, u, v, w, x, z, æ, ð,
ŋ, ɑ, ɑ̃, ɒ, ɔ, ə, ɚ, ɛ, ɜ, ɜ˞, ɝ,
ɡ, ɪ, ɵ, ɹ, ɾ, ʃ, ʃ̩, ʊ, ʌ, ʒ, ʤ,
θ, ∅


Python treats ASCII and Unicode characters unformly. They're each just one element of the string, you shouldn't have to do anything special.

Make sure you specify the correct encoding when you open the file for reading.

Do the answers to this question help at all?

@Barmar if I load the file with encoding='utf-8' it has no effect on the outcome described here

WHat do you mean by # contains IPA char? Where is the IPA character in that?

@Barmar maybe I am not using the terminology exactly accurately, but it is a file of words and their IPA pronunciation representations. In this case, the syllable is 'tyl' and the pronunciation for that syllable mapped to 'tl̩' which is 't' and an 'l' with a tiny ligature underneath....

It's not erroneous; you just failed to consider that the string contains three distinct characters which are rendered as a pair of glyphs.

@slashdottir, what you are looking at is not "an IPA char" (there is no such thing), but a "grapheme" or a "grapheme cluster". That is, multiple unicode characters which are combined to form (taking some steps) one single glyph.

The string tl̩ is actually three characters: ASCII tl followed by U+0329 COMBINING VERTICAL LINE BELOW.

@slashdottir your question would be addressed by using grapheme clusters. But I don't know what your fully phonemic repertoire is in your data. Grapheme clusters will only work with some IPA combinations and not others. Without knowing the full inventory it is hard to know if grapheme clusters will give you a complete solution or a partial solution.

@Andj that's a fair question. I will update the post with the full list of phonetic characters I need to handle in my project.

@slashdottir, thanks, the list helps, i will need to give it some thought, the modifiers mean that a grapheme based approach will definitely not work for you, so given new information existing answers are obsolete. The data uses : instead of ː and uses both ɝ and ɜ˞ and some of the older ligatures that were withdrawn from the IPA.

@user2722968 the question needs to segment IPA symbols, not graphemes. An IPA symbol can be one or more Unicode characters, it can also be one or more extended grapheme clusters.

@Andj Yeah, I should have excluded the ones with colon indicators as for my project they don't really add enough interesting info.  Away they go.

Here's a solution that works though it includes a hack to handle the rhotic hook
def get_last_character_and_length(s):
  matches = regex.findall(r'[\w\W][\u0300-\u036f\u02B0-\u02FF]*˞?', s)
  last_character = matches[-1] if matches else None
  return last_character, len(last_character) if last_character else 0

examples
    syl1 = 'tyl'  # plain ascii
    c, c_l = get_last_character_and_length(syl1)
    assert(c == 'l')
    assert(c_l == 1)

    syl2 = 'tl̩'  # contains IPA
    c, c_l = get_last_character_and_length(syl2)
    assert(c == 'l̩')
    assert(c_l == 2)

    syl3 = 'stɜ˞' # contains rhotic hook
    c, c_l = get_last_character_and_length(syl3)
    assert(c == 'ɜ˞')
    assert(c_l == 2)


What you are probably looking for (without knowing it) is the string's last grapheme. Resist the temptation to "cut" the string via unicode codepoints (as some comments and answers here suggest), as this will lead to plain wrong results; read the links provided previously.
You can do so e.g. using the grapheme package:
import grapheme

syl = 'tl̩'
*_, last = grapheme.graphemes(syl)
assert last == 'l̩'
assert len(last) == 2


The grapheme module is fairly obsolete, it's based on a fairly old version of Unicode. Better to use PyICU with a recent version of icu4c and a character level break iterator which will break on grapheme clusters. Or use pyuegc. Also grapheme clusters will only address some aspects of IPA for more complete coverage you'd need a different solution to grapheme clusters which can't handle IPA sequences with multiple characters with a combining class of 0.

Tried this solution, it also separates 'ɜ˞' into '˞' and 'ɜ'

@slashdottir, those are seperate (extended) grepheme clusters; even Unicode can't help you with that.

@user2722968 Unicode does mention the possibility  and need for tailoring grapheme clusters. It also has a lot of information of text segmentation and line breaking. This issue isn't whether Unicode covers these edge cases (it does), rather the issue is how do you do it in python in the absence of python supporting it internally.

The unicodedata module can give you information about each of the Unicode codepoints in the string.
import unicodedata
text = 'tl̩'
last_char = ''
for i in range(len(text)-1, -1, -1):
    last_char = text[i] + last_char
    if unicodedata.combining(text[i]) == 0:
        break

last_char
'l̩'
len(last_char)
2


This will work in cases where the IPA Symbol contains only one character of a combining class 0. But many IPA symbols contain more than one character with combining class 0, i.e an IPA symbol may consist of more than one grapheme cluster. Your solution will work for the question as worded, but the question does not indicate the full inventory in the data, so it is unknown whether this solution will work for all cases in the data.

@Andj I can't be blamed for inadequacies of the question.

I know. The question is flawed. But all answers so far make assumptions about IPA symbols that are incorrect.

Your answer may work perfectly fine with the data, but we don't know if it does or not. A complete answer would involve writing a break iterator for IPA,  a painful task.

@Andj you're perfectly free to write your own answer.

Ok I tried this answer, but I'm finding that 'ɜ˞' is getting separated into '˞' and 'ɜ'

@MarkRansom, when I have the time, I will see if i can create a generic IPA character level Break Iterator, I need to first define the rules needed then insert them into the default character (grapheme) level break iterator rules: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/unicode-org/icu/refs/heads/main/icu4c/source/data/brkitr/rules/char.txt

@Andj I look forward to seeing it, let me know when it's up.

Grab the last character if it's alphabetical, otherwise grab the last two.
syl[-1 if syl[-1].isalpha() else -2:]


This is not even wrong, it's so wrong.

@user2722968 Why do you think it's wrong? It works fairly well for my example at least..     syl = 'tl̩'
last_char = syl[-1 if syl[-1].isalpha() else -2:]
# becomes 'l̩' which is correct


This is just guesswork where no guesswork is required. There are many more graphemes made of more than two code points, and one has to adhere to the standard to correctly decode them. E.g. your code fails badly on hebrew הַֽ.

@user2722968 Ok, I guess it works for my limited case but maybe not all potential cases. I do like the simplicity of it though

@user2722968 yes the answer is incorrect, but all the other answers are also potentially incorrect. We don't know the phonemic inventory of the data. We are given only one example. An IPA symbol may consist of one OR more graphemes. We don't know what IPA symbols are present in the data. This answer isn't optimum, but it does address the example in the question. But the other answers aren't necessarily any more correct.

Geez this question turned out to be way more contentious than I anticipated, lol

The overall discussion has been very interesting, and I've learned some neat stuff despite having some egg on my face, haha.
